# Yau's conjecture for positive Chern class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde

I heard in a conference that Yau's conjecture is open for positive Chern class. I read in an article that talked about some stability conditions necessary in this case. So I want to know if this stability condition is well-determined or still conjectural. More precisely, is there any precise statement of this conjecture or is it open ended?

Comment: I would like to call the attention of the moderators of MO.  What started as a good question and informative answer now seems to have been hijacked by (apparently) anonymous users to argue one side of a dispute.  Without taking any position on that dispute, I do not feel MO is the proper place for such arguments.

Comment: A recent article by X. Chen, S. Sun and S. Donaldson http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~skdona/KEDEVELOPMENTS-9-19-2013.PDF

Comment: can anyone tell me the point of proving KE by stability?
It seems that stability is a harder thing compared with KE
but why use a complicated thing to explain an easier concept of KE?

Comment: @user43004: As I understand it, stability is purely algebraic, so we can check it explicitly in many algebraic varieties, if we can write down algebraic descriptions of the varieties. KE metrics, although somehow more comfortable for differential geometers, and admitting deep consequences, are not explicitly written down on typical KE manifolds. So proving stability is often easier than proving KE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A precise statement and proof of the relationship between stability and the existence of Calabi-Yau metrics is in:

1. arXiv:1302.0282, Xiuxiong Chen, Simon Donaldson, Song Sun, 
   *Kahler-Einstein metrics on Fano manifolds, III: limits as cone angle approaches 2π and completion of the main proof*
2. arXiv:1212.4714, Xiuxiong Chen, Simon Donaldson, Song Sun,
   *Kahler-Einstein metrics on Fano manifolds, II: limits with cone angle less than 2 π*
3. arXiv:1211.4566, Xiu-Xiong Chen, Simon Donaldson, Song Sun, 
   *Kahler-Einstein metrics on Fano manifolds, I: approximation of metrics with cone singularities*
4. arXiv:1210.7494, Xiu-Xiong Chen, Simon Donaldson, Song Sun
   *Kahler-Einstein metrics and stability*
5. arXiv:1211.4669, Gang Tian, *K-stability and Kähler-Einstein metrics*

(so I understand; I haven't read all of this)

Comment: It's worth noting that the above preprints prove that K-stable implies the existence of a Kahler-Einstein metric. The other direction was proven when there are no automorphisms by Donaldson (KE implies K-semistability), Stoppa (KE implies K-stability) and in the presence of automorphsims by Berman.

Comment: Its also worth noting that as far as I understand, Tian has also posted a preprint with these results: arXiv:1211.4669.

Comment: Yes, maybe for the sake of completeness, and since moreover your answer has been accepted, you could add also Tian's contribution to the subject. Best,

Comment: Might be worth recording here that Chen-Donaldson-Sun were awarded the Veblen prize for their work: http://www.ams.org/news?news_id=4705.